# How to detect via IPN when user request refund from Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, detect, paypal-ipn

I code a website (PHP) that allow user add fund via Paypal. I use IPN to get result and insert data into database. That 's step is okay.

However I wonder if a user login to Paypal and refund, I don't know how to detect that action occurs. Does any method return from Paypal via IPN that alert me when refund ?

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 2):

See https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference#id091EB04C0HS

Under Payment Information Variables, see the description for mc_fee and mc_gross:

**mc_fee**: Transaction fee associated with the payment. mc_gross minus mc_fee equals the amount deposited into the receiver_email account. Equivalent to payment_fee for USD payments. If this amount is negative, it signifies a refund or reversal, and either of those payment statuses can be for the full or partial amount of the original transaction fee.

**mc_gross**: Full amount of the customer's payment, before transaction fee is subtracted. Equivalent to payment_gross for USD payments. If this amount is negative, it signifies a refund or reversal, and either of those payment statuses can be for the full or partial amount of the original transaction.

Same goes for payment_fee, etc. Just use that *IPN Variable Reference* page and do a search for "refund" to see which variables you want to evaluate in your own code.

Comment: I don't understand a bit, if a user add fund today on my website I can get some variables (mc_gross, mc_fee,...) at that time. However after 2,3 days, the user make refund on Paypal website how can I get variables because in that time have no any connection between my website ( my code) and Paypal ?

Sorry about my English !

Thanks !

Comment: Please take a moment to view PayPal's IPN Protocol and Architecture section of their Introducing IPN page (https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro#id089BD0706YK). There are a number of ways IPNs are sent out, not just in connection with your website. Quote: "PayPal generates an IPN message when you perform actions that invoke the PayPal API, regardless of whether it is from your website or from a back-office or administrative procedure." So in your IPN listener, if you want to detect refunds, look at the amount. Negative = refund.